# jsoup clean includes unwanted carriage return

Tags: java, jsoup

This is currently vexing me.

Jsoup is including an extra line break in the returned string if the string includes `<br />`

eg.

```
String html ="TEST<br />TEST";

Jsoup.clean(html, org.jsoup.safety.Whitelist.basic());
```

returns

```
TEST\n<br />TEST
```

Any advice on how to avoid the inclusion of the troublesome \n?

Comment: jsoup is open source. You can modify it if you don't like the behavior.

Comment: Hi nhahtdh. It is just that the behaviour seems so odd I was assuming there was an out of the box solution or a trusted, performant workaround.

Comment: Anyone landing on this page with the same issue, you might want to read the answers on this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503117/jsoup-line-feed. In short, checkout jsoup's OutputSettings config class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `.text();` or `.ownText();` from the `Elements` class?

```
//If you want the whole page
String url = "http://www.yourwebsite.com";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
System.out.println(doc.text());

//If you want some specific part of the page
Elements elems = doc.select("query");

for (Element element : elems) {
    System.out.println(element.text() + "\n");
    System.out.println(element.ownText() + "\n\n");
}
```

If each `element` returned `< p>Hello< b> there< /b> now!< /p>`

1. The method `text();` would return `Hello there now!`
2. The method `ownText();` would return `Hello now!`

Just to make it easier to understand: The `.text();` will return the whole text within the tag you got. The `ownText();` method will return the text from the tag itself, and not the text from its children.

About the query in `doc.select("query");`, you can search [here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) for any pattern you want.

Comment: Hi Igor. Any chance you could give an example please?

Comment: I edited my answer. If you have any further questions, just ask.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Cleaner cleaner = new Cleaner(WHITE_LIST);
    Document clean = cleaner.clean(body);
    Document.OutputSettings outputSettings = new Document.OutputSettings();
    outputSettings.prettyPrint(false);
    clean.outputSettings(outputSettings);
    return clean.body().html();
```

outputSettings.prettyPrint(false);