# jsoup line feed

Tags: jsoup

We're using Jsoup.clean(String, Whitelist) to process some input, and it appears that Jsoup is adding an extraneous line break just prior to acceptable tags. I've seen a few people post this issue around the internet, but haven't been able to track down a solution.

For instance, let's say we have a very simple string with some bold tags within it, like so:

```
String htmlToClean = "This is a line with <b>bold text</b> within it."                                                                                                                                                       
String returnString =  Jsoup.clean(htmlToClean, Whitelist.relaxed());
System.out.println(returnString);
```

What comes out of the call to the clean() method is something like so:

```
This is a line with \n<b>bold text</b> within it.
```

Notice that extraneous "\n" appended just prior to the opening bold tag. I can't seem to track down in the source where this is being appended (although admittedly I'm new to Jsoup).

Has anyone encountered this problem, and better yet, have found some way to avoid this extra, unwanted character to be appended to the string in this way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hmm... have not seen any options for this.

If you parse the html in `Document` you have some output settings:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(htmlToClean);
doc.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false);

System.out.println(doc.body().html());
```

With `prettyPrint` off you'll get the following output: `This is a line with <b>bold text</b> within it.`

Maybe you can write your own `clean()` method, since the implemented one useses `Document`'s (there' you can disable `prettyPrint`):

**Orginal methods:**

```
public static String clean(String bodyHtml, Whitelist whitelist) {
    return clean(bodyHtml, "", whitelist);
}

public static String clean(String bodyHtml, String baseUri, Whitelist whitelist) {
    Document dirty = parseBodyFragment(bodyHtml, baseUri);
    Cleaner cleaner = new Cleaner(whitelist);
    Document clean = cleaner.clean(dirty);
    return clean.body().html();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate you taking the time to provide some advice. Indeed, modifying my code to do the following steps fixed the problem of the appended line break, and retained all the required whitelisting  code. Much obliged. 

    `Document dirty = Parser.parseBodyFragment(html, "");`
    `Cleaner cleaner = new Cleaner(Whitelist.relaxed());`   
    `Document clean = cleaner.clean(dirty);`  
    `clean.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false);`  
    `return clean.body().html();`

Sorry about the lack of line breaks in this comment, I don't believe this is supported in the markup.

Answer (score 8):

### Addendum:

I just downloaded **Jsoup 1.7.1**, in this version it's possible to use `clean()`-method with custom `OutputSettings`:

```
String html = "This is a line with <b>bold text</b> within it.";

OutputSettings settings = new OutputSettings();
settings.prettyPrint(false);

String clean = Jsoup.clean(html, "", Whitelist.relaxed(), settings);
```

Or shorter:

```
String clean = Jsoup.clean(html, "", Whitelist.relaxed(), new OutputSettings().prettyPrint(false));
```

*(In fact its the same solution like posted in the comments)*