# JSoup adding extra <br /> 's

Tags: jsoup

JSoup seems to be adding extra br tags to my output as shown below. Is there a way to stop this from happening ?

JUnit Test :

```
@Test
public void testJsoup () throws MLException {
    String htmlBody = "<body> <div> <br class='calibre1'></br> <br class='calibre1'></br></div> </body>"; 
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlBody);
    htmlBody = doc.select("body").first().toString();
    System.out.println(htmlBody);
}
```

Console Output :

```
<body> 
 <div> 
   <br class="calibre1" />
   <br /> 
   <br class="calibre1" />
   <br />
 </div> 
</body>
```

Regards,
Danny

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any extra `<br />`-Tags here ... do you mean line feed instead?
If yes, have a look here: [jsoup line feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503117/jsoup-line-feed/12503413)

**What you can do is turning `prettyPrint` off:**

```
final String html = "<body> <div> <br class='calibre1'></br> <br class='calibre1'></br></div> </body>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

// This line will keep your Html in one line
doc.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false);

System.out.println(doc.body());
```

**Output:**

```
<body> <div> <br class="calibre1" /><br /> <br class="calibre1" /><br /></div> </body>
```

Comment: Hi Ollo, thanks, but I there is an extra <br /> in the output. Notice that the input contains this : "<br class='calibre1'></br>" , but in the output, it was converted to <br class="calibre1" /> <br />. In other words, the input is effectively 1 br tag (with an open and closing tag), but the output became 2 br tags (both self-closing).

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice that. Looks like something that can't be done with changing some settings. Could this be a bug?