# Return Line Breaks from Jsoup.parse

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm attempting to parse out the html tags from a Java string and that is working fine using the below Jsoup parse method.  The only thing is that when I call the .text method it removes the line breaks `("\n")` tags.  I want to keep those but still have the method return a String, any ideas?

```
 private static String stripHTML(String html) {
     return Jsoup.parse(html).text();
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried getOwnText()?

Comment: Check the solution given on this question "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503117/jsoup-line-feed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newlines aren't any different from spaces (or consecutive spaces or tabs) in HTML. What you pull out won't have any semantic meaning. <p> and <br />, on the other hand...

Comment: While this is true, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12580364/14731 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/5640334/14731 if you want to preserve newlines.