# Output JSoup without added spaces and line breaks around the elements

Tags: java, xml, jsoup, musicxml

I am parsing and outputting an xml file using JSoup (and modifying the elements in between of course).

The output file has some extra spaces and line breaks. I was wondering if I can print this in the original format.

Original:

```
  <attributes>
        <divisions>4</divisions>
        <key>
          <fifths>0</fifths>
          <mode>major</mode>
          </key>
...
```

New:

```
<attributes> 
    <divisions>
     4
    </divisions> 
    <key> 
     <fifths>
      0
     </fifths> 
     <mode>
      major
     </mode> 
    </key> 
...
```

Any idea on how to remove the spaces/enters from the elements?

I currently read in and print the document like this:

```
doc = Jsoup.parse(is, "UTF-8", "", Parser.xmlParser());


BufferedWriter htmlWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("output.xml"), "UTF-8"));
        htmlWriter.write(doc.toString());
```

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12503117/1700321 ?

Comment: Interesting, but isn't this the opposite, as it adds the \n to it?

Comment: I was referring more the `prettyPrint` and `OutputSettings` options.

Comment: Great, doc.outputSettings().indentAmount(0).prettyPrint(false); did it. Will you post it as an answer?

Comment: Well, you are the one who found it, I just pointed you in the right direction. :) You can answer your question yourself.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With some help from [Aleksandr M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1700321/aleksandr-m) I solved it in the following way:

```
doc.outputSettings().indentAmount(0).prettyPrint(false);
```

A little less nice, but this also seemed to do the trick:

```
htmlWriter.write(doc.toString().replaceAll(">\\s+",">").replaceAll("\\s+<","<"));
```

Comment: Thanks! `outputSettings()` is great.  `replaceAll()` is problematic in that it can join e.g. this: `A <b>doozy</b> dog` into this textual content: `Adoozydog`, right

Comment: In Javadocs, there is a line for this method `indentAmount(int indentAmount)` "Set the indent amount for pretty printing". I believe you wouldn't need to set `indent` to `0` if you're setting `prettyPrint `to `false`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
doc = Jsoup.parse(is, "UTF-8", "", Parser.xmlParser());
doc.outputSettings().escapeMode(Entities.EscapeMode.xhtml);
..
..
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Tried this, but no difference.